Laravel API URL not found on this server
I am trying to make API project by Laravel
I created the database and configured the .env file and installed the api with php:artisan
But when I tried to test the URL with Postman it http://localhost/api/units showed HTML code for page that said The requested URL was not found on this server.
.env
APP_NAME=SKYCENTRAL
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:havtW5AahJjp4acK6Wg8PvRewVywLlwzjcp9xdA2NnQ=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_TIMEZONE=UTC
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=skycentral
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=


api.php
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\UnitController;

Route::apiResource('units', UnitController::class);


controller
    public function index()
    {
        return Unit::all();
    }

Postman
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.58 (Win64) OpenSSL/3.1.3 PHP/8.2.12 Server at 
localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>

I checked the app.php to see if the api is installed successfully and I found that everthing is ok
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__ . '/../routes/web.php',
        api: __DIR__ . '/../routes/api.php',
        commands: __DIR__ . '/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up'
    )->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
    })->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
    })->create();

And when run php artisan route:list I found that the routes is showing successfully
GET|HEAD        /  
GET|HEAD        api/units units.index › UnitController@index  
POST            api/units units.store › UnitController@store  
GET|HEAD        api/units/{unit} 
units.show › UnitController@show  
PUT|PATCH       api/units/{unit} 
units.update › UnitController@update  
DELETE          api/units/{unit} 
units.destroy › UnitController@destroy
GET|HEAD        sanctum/csrf-cookie sanctum.csrf-cookie › 
Laravel\Sanctum › CsrfCookieController@show
GET|HEAD        up 


What is your access url from postman?

http://localhost/api/units
@Subha

Check if the route is correctly registered php artisan route:list

@OsamaElEmam, Should not it be the http://localhost:8000/api/units ? You can also run this php artisan route:list command to check valid route.

I updated the code to show you the registered routes
@Subha

@OsamaElEmam, Your routes seems correct to me. Run this comman php artisan route:cache and use the exact endpoint from postman that I mentioned above.

That's the Apache 404, not the Laravel 404, so it's not being routed properly. Make sure the Apache webroot is pointed to the public folder of your project.

please, how to check the apache webroot?
@aynber

It shows Apache and Windows, so are you using XAMPP? If so, you'll need to check the settings for that. I haven't used XAMPP in years, so couldn't tell you where to set it.

yeah xampp and this is the root
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
@aynber

Where is your project on your computer?

C/xampp/htdocs/skycentralback @aynber

Then your webroot needs to be pointed to C:/xampp/htdocs/skycentralback/public
